# Is it possible to get number of new records everday not repeated?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**I want to fetch 50 new records everyday.
if it is possible please let me know.
i get the random result but after sometimes records are repeating.plz any one gave an idea**
*//For Simple/Random Search*

```
function search($data,$designation){
    $this->db->select("*");
    foreach($designation as $single_data) $this->db->or_like("designation",$single_data);
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->like('name',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('designation',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('company',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('email',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('state',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('city',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('phone',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('country',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('pincode',$data);
    $this->db->group_end();
    $this->db->order_by('rand()');
    $this->db->limit(100);
    $this->db->from('content');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Records from where ?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: from database i edit my question and post my code

Comment: Given the limited information in your question, I assume if you have freedom to create a new table, you may want to keep a reference of the daily fetched records in another tables and exclude those records in your daily query.

Comment: You are using random. So you need to maintain one archive table where you can add daily records and then you can try query- `WHERE NOT EXISTS IN that archive table.`

Answer (score -1):

as I understand the question, you want to select random records, but for the remainder of the day, those 50 random records must be the same as the first time that day. Next day, new random records.

You could  therefor use an argument in rand() and keep that number the same for the day.
Let's take the unix timestamp of the current date

I will limit it to the important lines:

```
<?php
$ts = mktime(0,0,0, 06, 30 , 2017);
$this->db->order_by('rand('. $ts.')');
?>
```

Up to you to make the numbers in mktime change day by day
(date('d'), date('m') and date('Y'), but it won;t make the code more readable as example

--

ok completly then:

```
function search($data,$designation){
    $this->db->select("*");
    foreach($designation as $single_data) { 
        $this->db->or_like("designation",$single_data);
    }
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->like('name',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('designation',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('company',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('email',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('state',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('city',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('phone',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('country',$data);
    $this->db->or_like('pincode',$data);
    $this->db->group_end();
    $ts = mktime(0,0,0, date('m'), date('d') , date('Y');
    $this->db->order_by('rand('. $ts.')');
    $this->db->limit(100);
    $this->db->from('content');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

above code should give you 100 random records. Each day a different set, but throughout a day always the same (presummed you do not remove records from the table)

added { } to foreach. Not per se needed, but makes code more readable;

Comment: Please don't try to answer poor quality questions, especially not when it's unclear what was being asked.  Your answer depends on too many assumptions on what the question asker meant, and answering poor quality questions will only encourage further poor quality questions.

Comment: As english is not  my first language as it seems for TS, I try to read around badly formulated sentences.

Comment: its not give me proper result

Comment: because.... ? What is wrong? duplicates, not random, niet correct number of.. etc

Comment: I must, in retrospective, say to @GordonM he is right. It is a poor quality question. And also the extra comments are met with unclear remarks. We are now at a situation: "it's not working", "why?" "please help". With what? It's not particulary clear what you asked in the first place, althought I think I know what you wanted. But the answer is met with "not working". But as long as you don't say why not (syntax error, sorting wrong, getting too many/little records etc) No-one can really help, can he?